# VLC gets closed on pressing power button on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, vlc

I installed vlc using `sudo apt install vlc`

What I noticed is that, If I press the Power button when VLC is playing a video, then it closes VLC and gives the prompt of saying "system will power off in 60 seconds" with Cancel, Restart, Power Off options

But this didn't happen with any other application.

My Power button action is `power off`.

Edit : Not only Power button the same happens If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Delete</kbd> which is the default shortcut for logout

Comment: Did you notice if the VLC icon in the title bar is gone when the app closes? I had issues of the app closing but this was still active on the title bar and it was casues problems. I had to manually close it a few times to have it release the file that was playing. Maybe it has other effects as well?

Comment: yeah I faced that problem too then I turned it off through preferences